# Hard coded value works where as element.val() does not show results

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code works fine if the value of param is hard coded where as if the value is taken from the input field, then the function `getResults()` does not show the results(but the alert shows that the value has been successfully provided to `param`). Please guide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var nexturl ="";
var lastid ="";

$(document).ready(function() {

  //$("#search").keyup(function() {
    //$('#hit').click(function() {  

  //var param = $("#search").val(); 
 $("#search").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
    var param = $('#search').val();
        alert(param);

    }
});
  //$(document).ready(function() {
  //var param = "Facebook";
  if (param != "") {
    $("#status").show();
    var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=25&q='+param;
    getResults(u);
  };


  $("#more").click(function () { 

    $("#status").show();
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });

//};
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var nexturl ="";
var lastid ="";
var param;
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#search").keypress(function(e) {
    var param = $('#search').val();
    if (param != "") {
        $("#status").show();
        var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=25&q='+param;
        getResults(u);
        }
});
};


  $("#more").click(function () { 

    $("#status").show();
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you supply the getResults function, I don't see it? Also, my guess is that you are experiencing scope issues, but can't say for sure until I see the rest of your code.

Comment: @jamesemanon: Supplying that would make the code very lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your variable scope. `var param` is defined within the `.keypress` function and therefore its scope is local to that function, it can't be accessed by the other code below (which has scope in the `(document).ready`).

Also consider that even if it had global scope, your code still wouldn't work because `getResults()` executes on load and the `.keypress` function will obviously not execute until a key is pressed on `#search`.

Your best bet is probably to define it before `getResults()`:

```
var param = $('#search').val();
if (param != "") {
    $("#status").show();
    var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=25&q='+param;
    getResults(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On further thought (see comment).

define a global param:

```
var param = "";
```

then within your jQuery ready, assign values to param like so..

```
param = somevalue;
```

Do not use var param, within this scope.

Comment: while this will definitely work, it may not be the best solution if creating globals (particularly one called param) can cause a conflict with other scripts you have in your project. if you wrap the whole script in an object you'd be fine but if you don't want to do that then you should consider more carefully figuring out the correct scope